Does a price of a service have to be provided by businesses to customers before the service is provided?
I went to a new hairdressers today in Sussex for cut and blow dry. I pre booked the appointment, it didn’t cross my mind to ask the price and they didn’t tell me the price over the phone.
I arrived at the appointment, and signed in, but forgot to check the price. Again, they didn’t inform me the price.
I had the appointment and the stylist was very good, friendly, and I was happy with the service. However, when I came to pay at the end, I was surprised at the cost. It was about £25 more than I had spent at my usual hair salon.
I didn’t want to make any fuss so I just paid. I’m not sure if it is my fault for not asking or the hair salon’s for not telling me the cost in advance.
Are UK businesses legally obliged to confirm the price of a service before they undertake/provide the service to the customer?
TIA

Could they have had a price list (e.g. on the wall/in the window) that you might not have noticed?

but forgot to check the price. ... You did not bother to look? Prices are usually depicted quite large, which is all the laws demand.

As long as the price list is available, I think they're OK. They don't have to go out of their way to present them to you.

@TripeHound Does that matter? OP isn't asking what she might have missed; she's asking whether there's a law requiring a certain disclosure. The existence of a sign OP missed doesn't change what the law is.
